# Typescript errors on Angular 4 and Datejs

Tags: typescript, datejs, angular, typescript2.2

I am using **Angular 4.0.0** with **Typescript 2.2.1** and **datejs 1.0.0-rc3**. Anytime I am trying to compile the app (**npm start**), I am getting the following typescript error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/services/dates.service.ts:9:56 
    TS2339: Property 'getDay' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

The code:

```
/** dates.service.ts **/
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class CalendarService {

    DateJs: IDateJSStatic = <any>Date;

    getDay() {
            var day = this.DateJs.parse('2017-04-01').getDay();
            return day;
    }

}
```

Looking at the file `node_modules/@types/datejs/index.d.ts` the declaration for the function `parse()` is clearly **Date**:

```
/** Converts the specified string value into its JavaScript Date equivalent using culture-specific format information. */
parse(dateString: string): Date;
```

Does somebody know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Use the format method. Docs: https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/wiki/Format-Specifiers

```
DateJs: IDateJSStatic = Date as any;

getDay() {
    const day = new DateJs('2017-04-01')
    return day.format('l')
}
```